# Parquet file written with AvroParquetWriter is not accessible by Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet, parquet-mr

I am writing parquet file in local and uploading it to s3 using `AvroParquetWriter` and `AmazonS3` client. Then trying to access it from Spark.
Following is my code:

**AvroParquetWriter :**

```
try (ParquetWriter< MyData > writer = AvroParquetWriter.<MyData>builder("/tmp/file.parquet")
                .withSchema(ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(MyData.class))
                .withDataModel(ReflectData.get())
                .withConf(new Configuration())
                .withWriteMode(OVERWRITE)
                .build()) {
                writer.write(myData);
        }
```

**Uploading to s3:**

```
 s3client.putObject(bucketName, "path/file.parquet", new File("/tmp/file.parquet"));
```

**Reading From Spark:**

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucketname/path/file.parquet")
```

While reading parquet file from Spark, I am getting following exception:

> An error occurred while calling o379.parquet. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
>   in stage 3.0 (TID 15, ip-10-110-10-115.ec2.internal, executor 7):
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:538)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$9.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$9.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) **Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file:
>   FileStatus{path=s3://bucketname/path/file.parquet; isDirectory=false;
>   length=3920; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0;
>   access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
>     at**
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:551)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:538)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ThreadUtils.scala:287)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   **Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   s3://bucketname/path/file.parquet is not a Parquet file. expected
>   magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [120, 57, -43, 112]**
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:524)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:499)
>     at
>   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:476)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:544)
>     ... 9 more

**Please help me to solve this issue.**

Thanks

Comment: Can you read the local file using `AvroParquetReader` or does it only fail when reading from s3 via spark?

Comment: @JörnHorstmann I downloaded it to local machine and then tried to read using AvroParquetReader. It is working fine. But I have to also read it in spark directly from s3.

Comment: The error message sounds like the file might have been truncated when uploading to s3. The parquet reader expects a certain marker at the end of the file `expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49]`, those numbers are the ascii representaion of `PAR1`.